# freeradius + daloRadius WebGUI can't use broccade and a10 devices togehter

Tags: authentication, freeradius, daloradius

We have a freeradus server with daloradius as webfrontend on top.

Currently logins on Brocade Cisco etc. are all working as expected.
Now we are trying to add a A10 Thunder CGN to radius.

The Problem is, if we add the "A10-Priviledge-Level = 2" to the Answer attributes.
We are no longer able to log in to the brocade devices anymore.

Anyone else uses both of these devices together and got them both working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To End this we didn't actually find a Real Solution for the Problem.

But by now we decided to use the 2 A10 Devices without Radius (not that big of a deal since only two Persons Really need access to those Maschines).